# The import org.apache.cxf.ext cannot be resolved (org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingInInterceptor)

Tags: java, apache, log4j

Estoy implementando el siguiente método:

```
public static <T> T buildSoapInterface(final Class<T> apiType, AppProperties.ClientConf clientConf, String pathResources) {
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxy = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    proxy.setServiceClass(apiType);
    proxy.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    proxy.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(clientConf.getHost());
    builder.append(pathResources);
    proxy.setAddress(builder.toString());
    T service = (T) proxy.create();

    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) service;
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeOut",
            clientConf.getTimeout());
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout",
            clientConf.getTimeout());
    return service;
}
```

pero tengo problemas en la importacion de las clases LoggingInInterceptor y LoggingOutInterceptor.

```
    proxy.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    proxy.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

Usando la siguiente paqueteria

```
   import org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingInInterceptor;
   import org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingOutInterceptor;
```

Pero si uso estas

```
   import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor;
   import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
```

Recibo este error "*The type LoggingInInterceptor is deprecated*"

Y si busco en la documentación, sí esta, en la lista de clases deprecadas:

https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/deprecated-list.html

Ademas, busque si la clase que ellos recomienda es privada o alguna condición del cual no se pueda acceder, pero revisando la documentación me encuentro que si se puede usar, y si existe:

https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/ext/logging/LoggingInInterceptor.html

entonces no entiendo porque no funciona.
En mi pom yo tengo lo siguiente para cxf:

```
<!-- Apache Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Apache Log4j -->

    <!-- Apache CXFLog4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <!-- Jetty is needed if you're are not using the CXFServlet -->
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Apache CXFLog4j -->
    <!-- End Apache -->
```

Me podrían ayudar como implementar esto con código java y no por configuracion con los xml. Es por requerimiento no es porque no quiera hacerlo por xml.

Answer (score 0):

Debes eliminar la línea

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

de la dependencia

```
<artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
```

ya que te limita la visibilidad de la dependencia a solo modo "test" y por tanto no las puedes ver en modo compilacion por ejemplo.